# how to limit_choices_to self field id in django model

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

[image]how use limit_choices_to in django

```
class Category(models.Model):
    """
       商品类别
    """
    CATEGORY_TYPE = (
        (1, "一级类目"),
        (2, "二级类目"),
        (3, "三级类目"),
    )
    def limit_category_type_choice(self):
        obj = Category.objects.get(category_type=self.category_type)
        field_object = Category._meta.get_field('category_type')
        field_value = field_object.value_from_object(obj)
        return {'category_type__lte': field_value}


    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='category_id')
    category_title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50, verbose_name='目录标题', help_text='目录标题')
    category_name = models.ForeignKey(LinkDesignate,blank=True, null=True, to_field='link_des_text_id', related_name='category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category_type = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY_TYPE, verbose_name="类目级别", help_text="类目级别")
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey("self", limit_choices_to=self.limit_category_type_choice, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="父类目级别", help_text="父目录",
                                        related_name="sub_cat", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "产品目录"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
```

i know this

```
     limit_choices_to=self.limit_category_type_choice,
```

this is wrong , because name 'self' is not defined
how can to use the function limit_category_type_choice

the document is:

```
   def limit_pub_date_choices():
       return {'pub_date__lte': datetime.date.utcnow()}

   limit_choices_to = limit_pub_date_choices
```

how can i change my Function limit_category_type_choice without self
but can use the self instance

Comment: You can not `limit_choices_to` on a self field. Here you basically just passed the field definition as value, not the value in that field of a `self`.

Comment: i want to limit the category_type  is less than self.category_type .

Answer (score -1):

Put the `def` out of the class ;-)
This was my solution, it is similar.
It limits the films which can be choosen for an event.

1. Films with `status` '2' in class Film over `ForeignKey` OR
2. over reverse `ForeignKey`: Films with an Event with date in the future

the model:

```
def limit_film_choices():
    date = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    result = Q( status = '2') | Q( event_film__date__gte = date) 
    return result

class Film(models.Model):   
    STATUS_COICES = [
        ('1' , 'a'),
        ('2' , 'b'),
    ]
    status =  models.CharField( max_length=16, choices=STATUS_COICES,  default='1')

class Event(models.Model):
    film = models.ForeignKey('filme.Film', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_query_name='event_film',
        related_name='event_film',  blank = True, null=True, limit_choices_to = limit_film_choices)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True)
```